# Deleting primary commerce address throws error

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce

When i try to delete a user address in Craft Commerce, I get an error thrown, saying the address id does not exist.

However the address id being passed to the action is output from a loop of the current addresses, so it does exist?

This only happens if it is the primary shipping or billing address. If there is a single address, where its neither the primary shipping or billing address the error does not occur.

For example:

```
{% for address in customer.addresses %}
{% include 'shop/_includes/addresses/address' with {'address': address} %}
<form method="POST">
 <input type="hidden" name="action" value="commerce/customer-addresses/delete">
 {{ csrfInput() }}
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ address.id }}"/>
 <input type="submit" class="default-button" value="Delete"/>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

The error is attached in the following screenshot [image]:

This is using the default form/examples from the craft commerce example template - wondering what might be causing this error and how i can fix it?

If refresh the page the address is deleted as expected, but i can't get around the error being thrown.

Comment: The error is being thrown on saving an address, are you trying to save an address?

Comment: No i'm not trying to save the address - I'm justing using the example form above to delete e.g. posting the id to commerce/customer-addresses/delete

Comment: To be honest i'm not too sure how its getting to the saveAddress function, as the contents of the form being submitted only have that single action to delete addresses - i've checked through and there's doesn't seem to be anything else on the page (other forms etc) that might be interfering somehow.

Comment: @alexr this was a bug that has been fixed in the latest version of Commerce. Thanks!